# ExtJS Tab Panels

Tags: vb.net, extjs

So I'm adding a tab panel to a child window. A lot of our controls here are user defined but this looks like an ExtJS issue. When I add a tab panel, and then try and add controls and stuff to that panel, everything is cut off on that panel.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Using ViewDetailsWin As New Pages.ChildWindow
        With ViewDetailsWin
            .IconCls = Model.WorkflowStepDefinition.SmallIcon
            .Ref = "viewDetailsWin"
            .RenderTo = "workspacePanel.getEl()"
            .DestroyerRef = "mainPanel"
            .MethodName = "getViewDetailsWin"
            .Title = "View Details/Amortization Schedule"
            .Layout = Pages.Panel.LayoutType.Form
            .Closable = True
            .CloseAction = Pages.Window.CloseActionType.Hide
            .Maximizable = False
            .Modal = False
            .Height = 700
            .Width = 1000
            .BodyStyle = "padding:10px"

            .Toolbar.AddButton("Close", "function(){getViewDetailsWin().hide();}", "icon-button-cancel", , "Close")
            .Toolbar.AddButton("Select This Loan Terms Scenario", "function(){getViewDetailsWin().hide();}", "icon-button-save", , "Save")
            With .AddPanel()
                Dim Tabs As String() = {"Details", "Amortization Schedule"}
                Dim tabCollection As TabCollection = .AddTabs(Tabs)
                With tabCollection
                    With .Item(1)
                        With .AddFieldSet("Loan Calculation Results")
                            Dim ddlCalculateFor As New Controls.ComboBox("CalculateFor", "../../calculateFor", "Calculate For")
                            With ddlCalculateFor
                                .DisplayField = "LookupDesc"
                                .ValueField = "LookupID"
                                .ForceSelection = False
                                If Model.CalculateForId > 0 Then
                                    .Value = Model.CalculateForId
                                End If
                                .ReadOnly = True
                                .BindData(Model.CalculateForMethods)
                            End With
                            .AddControl(ddlCalculateFor)
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
            ViewResponse.AddScript(.ToJSObject("viewDetailsWin"))
        End With
    End Using
```

I can't even see the dropdown at all unless I scroll on the tiny little scroll bar it creates. It gives like a quarter inch on the screen to see anything inside the tab panel. There is no size property on the tab panel from what I can see.

This has been eating up my whole entire day. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the window AND the child panels have to be using the layout type 'FIT'.